# Hibernate JDBC returning a duplicate row

Tags: sql, hibernate, jdbc, duplicates

Hope I can make my problem clear:

I am using

```
HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam()
```

I find that in the return `list`, one record is being returned twice. And another record is expected, but it is replaced with the duplicated record. I have no idea how I can debug this, I inspected the `SQL` and when I enter it into SQL Developer, results are expected.

For example, expect:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Got:
1
2
3
3
5
6
7
8
9

Any help please? The `.equals` is the same for two of the returned records. And I can guarantee that we have no duplicate in the database. Please help, it is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: how is your entity mapping class looks like?

Comment: without code nobody can help you..so add some needed code like implementation of findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam method.